# In Israel, is there an official body or the only officially recognized body that calculates the Hebrew calendar

Tags: calendar

In Israel, is there an official body or the only officially recognized body that calculates the Hebrew calendar that establishes the conversion relationship between the Hebrew calendar and the Gregorian calendar for a period of time to confirm the use of the Hebrew calendar  legal public holidays, etc., so that the Hebrew calendar formulated by this institution has the sole legality in Israel?